# Is there a way to replace several occurences in a HTML file in one line?

Tags: node.js

Please can you tell me how to  make shorter this code. i wanna do it in one line.

```
var htmlstring = "<a href="{{1}}">{{1}}</a>Hello {{2}}, clic here !";
var firststep = htmlstring.replace('{{1}}', "http://google.fr");
var secondstep = htmlstring.replace('{{1}}', "http://google.fr");
var thirdstep = secondstep.replacee('{{2}}', "Mister");
```

In short,
I have it:

```
<a href="{{1}}">{{1}}</a>Hello {{2}}, clic here !
```

I wanna have this at the end:

```
<a href="http://google.fr">http://google.fr</a>Hello Mister, clic here !"
```

Comment: You could just put it in one line if that's all you want

Comment: Or use a templating lib, e.g. mustache.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how do achieve it using regex, because the replace function requires only 2 arguments. I don't want any libs.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
const html = '<a href="{{1}}">{{1}}</a>Hello {{2}}, click here !'
const url = 'http://google.fr';
const name = 'Mister';
const output = html.replace(/\{\{1\}\}/g, url).replace(/\{\{2\}\}/g, name);
```

Comment: Okay, but I want to replace also  {{2}} by Mister. All of that in one line.

Comment: @J.Doe if extending prototype is acceptable for you - I can suggest even better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have no Idea how you can replace both `{{1}}` and `{{2}}` in one go, but you can replace both occurences of `{{1}}` by using this function:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

Use it like this:

```
var htmlstring = '<a href="{{1}}">{{1}}</a>Hello {{2}}, clic here !';
htmlstring.replaceAll("{{1}}", "http://google.fr");
htmlstring.replaceAll("{{2}}", "Mister");
```

---

ES6 Update:

You can now use an even better function for the `replaceAll()` method:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
  return this.split(search).join(replacement);
};
```

This will utilize `.split()` to first make an array without the search value and then `.join()` that Array with the replacement:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {return this.split(search).join(replacement);};


let htmlstring = `<a href="{{1}}">{{1}}</a>Hello {{2}}, click here !`;

console.log(htmlstring.replaceAll("{{1}}","https://google.fr").replaceAll("{{2}}", "Mister"));
```